# Count all occurrences of text in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to count all occurrences of a particular word in a `varchar(200)` column.

My data is something like this:

```
ID    MyText
---   --------------------------------------
1     Hello how are you doing? Hello again.
2     This is great.
3     Hello my special person.
```

So I want SQL to do a like '%Hello%' and come back with the number 3. I don't care right now is for instance partial words are included and don't care right now on the like with wildcards. I only need this for some simple testing to validate some things.

Comment: I also don't care about case of the words either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH T(ID,MyText) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'Hello how are you doing? Hello again.' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'This is great.' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Hello my special person.'
)
SELECT *, 
       (LEN(MyText) - LEN(REPLACE(MyText, 'Hello', ''))) / LEN('Hello') AS Num
FROM T
```

Or

```
SELECT  SUM((LEN(MyText) - LEN(REPLACE(MyText, 'Hello', ''))) / LEN('Hello'))
FROM T
```

for an aggregate result

Comment: Thats cool! What if I change the varchar to a text field thou, just curious.